# Having trouble with my citations

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

So I'm having problems with the implementation of biblatex-chicago. When I compile the document only some of the information for each citation actually gets into the document, and it seems to be linked to what order the information appears in the .bib file. How do I fix this?

Also, can I add page numbers to the ends of the footnotes? I can't seem to find that either.

Document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\bibliography{article.bib}

\begin{document}

Rameau's work was very important in that it became the foundation of the study of music theory which continues to this day. Later the earliest formal definition of "tonality" was given by the Belgian composer Joseph Fetis,\footcite{Dahlhaus1990,Reti1978} though the word was used earlier by Alexandre Choron.\footcite{Choron1810}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@book{Choron1810,
    author = {Choron, Alexandre},
    year = {1810},
    title = {Dictionnaire historique des musiciens artistes et amateurs, morts ou vivants: qui se sont illustrés en une partie quelconque de la musique et des arts qui y sont relatifs ... ; précédé d'un sommaire de l'histoire de la musique}
    publisher = {Valade et Lenormant},
    address = {Paris}
    }

@book{cope2001,
    author = {David Cope},
    year = {2001},
    title = {New Directions in Music}
    edition = {Seventh},
    publisher = {Waveland Press},
    address = {Prospect Heights, III}
    }

@book{Dahlhaus1990,
    author = {Carl Dahlhaus},
    year = {1990},
    title = {Studies on the origin of harmonic tonality}
    publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    address = {41 William Street, Princeton, New Jersey 08540}
    }

@book{Rameau1722,
    author = {Jean-Philippe Rameau},
    translator = {Philip Goessett}
    year = {1722},
    title = {Studies on the origin of harmonic tonality}
    publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    address = {41 William Street, Princeton, New Jersey 08540}
    }

@book{Reti1978,
    author = {Rudolph Reti},
    year = {1978},
    title = {Tonality, atonality, pantonality :a study of some trends in twentieth century music}
    publisher = {Greenwood Publishing Group},
    address = {Westport, CT}
    }

@book{Schenker1954,
    author = {Heinrich Schenker},
    translator = {Elisabeth Mann Borgese}
    editor = {Oswald Jones}
    year = {1954},
    title = {Harmony}
    publisher = {The University of Chicago Press},
    }

@book{Schoenberg1911,
    author = {Arnold Schoenberg},
    year = {1911},
    title = {Theory of Harmony}
    translator = {Roy E. Carter}
    publisher = {Faber and Faber},
    }
```

Output in the footnote:

> 1. Carl Dahlhaus, Studies on the origin of harmonic tonality (1990); Rudolph Reti, Tonality, atonality, pantonality :a study of some trends
>      in twentieth century music
>      (1978).
> 2. Alexandre Choron, Dictionnaire historique des musiciens artistes et amateurs, morts ou vivants: qui se sont illustrs en une partie
>      quelconque de la musique et des arts qui y sont relatifs ... ; prcd
>      d'un sommaire de l'histoire de la musique (1810).

Bibliography output:

> References
>
> Choron, Alexandre. Dictionnaire historique des musiciens artistes et
>   amateurs, morts ou vivants: qui se sont illustrs en une partie
>   quelconque de la musique et des arts qui y sont relatifs ... ; prcd
>   d'un sommaire de l'histoire de la musique.
>   1810.
>
> Dahlhaus, Carl. Studies on the origin of harmonic tonality. 1990.
>
> Rameau, Jean-Philippe. Translated by Philip Goessett.
>
> Reti, Rudolph. Tonality, atonality, pantonality :a study of some
>   trends in twentieth century music. 1978.
>
> Schenker, Heinrich. Translated by Elisabeth Mann Borgese.
>
> Schoenberg, Arnold. Theory of Harmony. 1911.

Comment: Glad to see another music scholar using LaTeX on TeX.SX! Welcome!

Comment: To add page numbers for a citation, put the page range in square brackets before the citation key in curly brackets, like this: `\autocite[34--42]{Schoenberg1911}`.

Answer (score 1):

There were several small errors in your source file and commands. You were missing commas after some of the fields in the `.bib` file, which meant the file wouldn't parse correctly. Also, you need to pass some additional options to `biblatex-chicago`.

I corrected the style of the `.bib` entries to conform to Chicago style (headline-style capitalization for titles; only city, not full address for publishers).

Here is a working minimal example. Please take note of the comments. If you save as `musicbib.tex`, then compile with `pdflatex musicbib`, `biber musicbib`, then `pdflatex musicbib` twice.

```
\documentclass{article}

% These are needed for UTF8 characters to render properly with latex or pdflatex engines
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Note added options to specify notes-and-bibliography format, biber as backend engine, and encoding of biber file as utf8
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

% Note different command for adding bibliography file
\addbibresource{article.bib}

% Just for example on TeX.SX: produces external .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{article.bib}
@book{Choron1810,
    author = {Choron, Alexandre},
    year = 1810, % braces not needed for numeric data
    title = {Dictionnaire historique des musiciens artistes et amateurs, morts ou vivants: qui se sont illustrés en une partie quelconque de la musique et des arts qui y sont relatifs ... ; précédé d'un sommaire de l'histoire de la musique}, % comma was missing
    shorttitle = {Dictionnaire historique}, % shorttitle is used in subsequent citations
    publisher = {Valade et Lenormant},
    location = {Paris} % Location, not "address"
}

@book{Dahlhaus1990,
    author = {Carl Dahlhaus},
    year = {1990},
    title = {Studies on the Origin of Harmonic Tonality}, % comma was missing
    publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    location = {Princeton} % only the city is needed
}

@book{Reti1978,
    author = {Rudolph Reti},
    year = 1978, 
    title = {Tonality, Atonality, Pantonality: 
             A Study of Some Trends in Twentieth Century Music}, % comma was missing
    shorttitle = {Tonality, Atonality, Pantonality},
    publisher = {Greenwood Publishing Group},
    location =  {Westport, CT}
}
\end{filecontents}
% Note also spelling of Gossett's name

\begin{document}

Rameau's work was very important in that it became the foundation of the study of music theory which continues to this day. 
Later the earliest formal definition of ``tonality'' % Note LaTeX-style quotation marks for curly quotes
was given by the Belgian composer Joseph Fétis,\autocite{Dahlhaus1990,Reti1978} % Note \autocite command, by default gives footnote citation (also missing accent on Fétis)
though the word was used earlier by Alexandre Choron.\autocite{Choron1810}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]